# SOLR: Same brand facet with different case

Tags: solr

I am getting following set of brand facet

```
Mink Pink(8)
MinkPink(8)
```

This two brands are same because of no space in second option it treated as different brand.

How can avoid this case so i should get only one brand facet in result as follows.

```
Mink Pink(8)
```

Comment: I think either you need to send the data in one of the form and index in solr or while indexing you need to remove the space and store the data

Comment: How do you know that "Mink Pink" is the correct form? Is this the only brand? Are there other brands you need to convert with specific rules? Usually this should be fixed in the data you're ingesting into Solr so that it's uniform when it hits Solr, but you can [apply a filter to change specific text](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory).